# Run rsync as root but keep target owner

Tags: rsync, ownership

I've already checked many threads regarding the topic and tried different flags combinations, but couldn't solve the problem.

Scenario: I'm working under user A and have source files owned by A, target files are owned by user B, I copy source to destination using rsync under sudo and want target files to stay owned by B after copying.

```
sudo rsync -ar src/ dst/
```

result: `A:A`

```
sudo rsync -ar --no-o src/ dst/
```

result: `B:A` (if files contents is same) or `root:A` (if files contents is different)

How can I keep `B:B` on target files?

For example, simple `sudo cp -r src/ dst/` can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `--chown=B:B`

From the `rsync` manual:

> `--chown=USER:GROUP`
>
> This option forces all files to be owned by `USER` with group
>             `GROUP`.  [...]  If either the `USER` or `GROUP`
>             is empty, no mapping for the omitted user/group will occur.  If
>             `GROUP` is empty, the trailing colon may be omitted, but if `USER`
>             is empty, a leading colon must be supplied. [...]

If you want to preserve the ownerships of the existing files on the destination side, then the easiest way to do that is to use both `--no-group` and `--no-user` and then post-process the destination files and directories in such a way that anything that is owned by root gets owned by the other user.

This could be done through

```
rsync -a --no-group --no-user src/ dst
```

(note that `-r` is implied by `-a`/`--archive`), and then

```
find dst -user  root -exec chown B {} +
find dst -group root -exec chgrp B {} +
```

This would find anything in or below `dst` that is owned by the root user or group (these would be new files added by `rsync` at the destination), and changes the owner and group of these to `B`.

Comment: But what if I don't know target owner or target files have mixed owners? I don't want to assign target owner, I want to keep it unchanged.

Comment: @o.v The easiest way to do that is to use both `--no-group` and `--no-user` and then post-process the destination files and directories in such a way that anything that is owned by root gets owned by the other user.  I will add this to the answer.